# Why error -- undefined function defstruct

Tags: elixir

I have this modules where I'm trying to define a struct:

```
defmodule A do
  defmodule B do
    defstruct :id, :name
  end
end
```

Why error?

```
undefined function defstruct/2
```

Why is this error?

Answer (score 5):

Elixir interprets `defstruct :id, :name` as calling `defstruct` with 2 arguments, that's the **/2** part in `undefined function defstruct/2`.

What you want to do is pass a single argument to defstruct, a list of field names:

```
defmodule A do
  defmodule B do
    defstruct [:id, :name]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Just check the [official documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#defstruct/1) in that matter.

You can use notation without square brackets, but you have be explicit and provide a keyword list. In example there are default values provided.

In your case `:id, :name` won't be keyword list and that's why compiler throw an error that you put there two arguments.

If you would do:

```
defmodule A do
  defstruct id: nil, name: nil
end
```

It would works perfectly fine.

Otherwise use explicitly list.